# Spelling out doses in method claims with “therapeutically effective dose” language

Tags: claims, means-plus-function

I’m writing method claims for a nutritional supplement like the following—

1. A method of reducing [a health condition] of a subject, comprising administering to the subject a therapeutically effective dose of A [for doing something], and a therapeutically effective dose of B.
2. The method recited in Claim 1, wherein A comprises one or more of the group consisting of C, D, and E.

A is means plus function while B, C, D and E are nutritional substances.

I’ve listed the therapeutically effective dose ranges of the nutritional substances in the specification, but do I need to spell these out in the claims? And do I need more “therapeutically effective dose” language in Claim 2?

Comment: I am not a chemist and I am not really familiar with this type of inventions, but depending on where you want to protect your inventiom maybe it is not advisable to include the term 'therapeutic' in the claims. Many countries, including the European ones, forbid the protection of [therapeutic methods](https://www.epo.org/law-practice/legal-texts/html/guidelines/e/g_ii_4_2.htm), so the word 'therapeutic' may increase the likelihood of receiving objections on the grounds of subject-matter being excluded from patentability.

Comment: Good to know. I'm not planning on filing outside the US, however.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer and would hesitate to suggest claim language. That said, you generally want a very broad claim in an application. Start with a claim without a specific range. Then have dependent claims where ranges are specified.

Comment: Don't make it only a method, claim the combination of substances as such too.